# How to make rice crispy treats with no marshmallows, eggs or gelaten

Tags: marshmallow

I'm trying to make rice crispy treats but I have no marshmallows, gelatin or eggs
What can I do

Comment: *rice crispy treats*? What kind? Please add the recipe.

Comment: THat's a lost cause, no ? even vegan rice crispy treats have vegan marshmallows

Comment: Go shopping? But seriously, please give us the kind of recipe you want to work with or modify - note that this is an international site and not all users will be familiar with the basic recipe.

Comment: Original Rice Krispy treats only have 3 ingredients: Rice Krispies (puffed rice cereal), marshmallows, and butter. Not sure how eggs or gelatin are relevant.

Comment: @Cindy gelatin to make marshmallows from scratch? And some recipes for marshmallows use eggs as well.

Comment: @Stephie   Duh! I didn't think of that! Afraid I have no viable solution.

Comment: This is like wanting to make french fries without potatoes - it kind of misses the point. As Stephie said, I think the answer is "go shopping".

Answer (score 6):

**Aquafaba**

> [Aquafaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquafaba) (/ˌɑːkwəˈfɑːbə/) is the name for the viscous water in which legume seeds such as chickpeas have been cooked.
>
> Due to its ability to mimic functional properties of egg whites in cooking, aquafaba can be used as a direct replacement for them in some cases, including meringues and marshmallows. Its composition makes it especially suitable for use by people with dietary, ethical, or religious reasons to avoid eggs.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquafaba)

Aqua Faba features heavily in Vegan cookbooks. You can get it by capturing the liquid when you drain a can of chickpeas.

[Here's](http://jerryjamesstone.com/recipe/vegan-rice-krispies-treats-aquafaba/) a recipe that might get you started.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have marshmallows, egg or gelatin do you have

- brown sugar
- butter
- vanilla and
- half-and-half?

If so you can make a [simple caramel](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ree-drummond/easy-caramel-sauce-recipe-2041446) that can bind your crispy treats. There are a variety of similar recipes that might use plain sugar, milk.

Do you have Honey, Molasses, or Karo? You will probably want to gently warm the stuff before mixing it with the rice crispies, but these would probably be a suitable binder.

If any of these make the treats 'too sticky' for your liking you can powder them with corn starch, cocoa, powdered sugar or cinnamon (or some combination there of)